I am using a multi-step form with Livewire. But when I go to the next step, my JavaScript call doesn't happen, although it works in the first step
This is my code:
`
@push('js')
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function (event) {
      
            Livewire.hook('message.processed', () => {
            const permissions = [
            @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
                {
                    label: "{{ $permission->TEMPLATE_NAME }}",
                    value: "{{ $permission->ID }}"
                },
            @endforeach
        \];
        VirtualSelect.init({
            ele: '#permissions',
            multiple: true,
            options: permissions,
        });
    });
});
    
@endpush

`
Please help me in providing a solution for this.
I need help with providing a solution for this. I searched a lot but didn't find anything. I am using Livewire 2. It works fine on the first page, and I am creating a multiselect dropdown.
